# When I Create New Table from Oracle Sql Developer. I get this error

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Error Messages:

ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1

ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're living a dangerous life.

**Never, ever create anything in SYS (nor SYSTEM) schema.**

Who knows what might be wrong ... maybe you dropped some SYS-owned object. Maybe there's a trigger which does "something" when you create a table.

There's nothing obvious in what you posted. Table, as is, creates normally:

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SCOTT"
SQL> create table table1
  2  (id varchar2(20) not null,
  3   ivoice varchar2(20) not null
  4  );

Table created.

SQL>
```

Comment: I'm new for oracle. How can i create new user and database from oracle18 XE. please give any tutorial.

Comment: You don't create a new database, just create a new user, with the CREATE USER command.  You can look that up in the documentation. https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/index.html.   If you are coming from MSSQL (as your question about creating a new database suggests), please note that the very concept of 'database' differs between the two.